# Is "to be likely doing something" a correct usage?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

We know that the **most likely** is commonly used in this way **"to be likely to do something"**. For instance **"He is likely to come to the party"**.

When it comes to the negative version of the same sentence, you would expect **They are most likely to not come to the party**. So far so good.

But, I have seen a usage where "most likely" is followed by a gerund "**They are most likely not coming to the party.**

Is using "most likely" with a gerund correct?

Comment: I don't understand why you say "so far so good." Before that you discuss the phrase "most likely", but then you give an example sentence that doesn't use that phrase. I'm also not sure why your question seems to focus on negative sentences whereas the title does not include any negative. Is "not" an important part of your question?

Comment: I say it, because until that point, I understand the usage of "most likely" with an infinitive. After that point, I ask what I am looking for an answer, because I am giving an example where "most likely" is being used with a gerund, which is what I can't be sure about.

Comment: **They are most likely to not come** is not idiomatic English. We would say **they are unlikely to come** or **they are likely to [stay away/decline the invitation/...]**

Comment: In the sentence you are asking about, I see **most likely** as an addition, qualifying the statement **They are not coming to the party**.